# can't save serialized data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

Here what I have on my code I dont see what is wrong on my code but I can't figured it out why it wont save on database.

My Array Details

```
Array
(
    [dates] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-01-18
            [1] => 2012-02-18
            [2] => 2012-03-18
            [3] => 2012-04-18
            [4] => 2012-05-18
        )

    [amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2000
            [1] => 2000
            [2] => 2000
            [3] => 2000
            [4] => 2000
        )

    [deposit] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

)
```

My saving code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO transaction (id, details)
        VALUES('$id', $serializeddetails)";

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Fatal error: ".mysql_error());
```

and I got this error

```
Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a:3:{s:5:"dates";a:6:{i:0;s:10:"2012-01-18";i:1;s:10:"2012-02-18";i:2;s:10:"2012' at line 2
```

I used longtext for my type of data and try longblob but no hope,

I try also use also base64_ecode();

```
$serializeddetails = base64_encode(serialize($detailsarray));
```

and got this error

```
Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2
```

what did I something wrong on my code why this wont save into database?

thank you

Comment: Are you forgetting to escape the values? Also, your first example isn't actually serializing anything... FWIW, this data could probably be stored in a more compact and language agnostic way if you `json_encode()` it instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that you shouldn't save serialized data in a database, check the [Database normalization article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for what tables you should have. I know its a quick solution to save the data in one field, but the problems come when you want to read tricky stuff like "show me the transactions on a given date" or "how many transaction has been done by the user per month".

Comment: @Progman: In general you are correct, but it's not strictly true that you should *never* do it - there are various reasons to store serialized data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO transaction (id, details)
        VALUES('$id', '$serializeddetails')";
```

`$serializeddetails` is a string, sou you need quotes. Also make sure, the serialized data is escaped. `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `addslashes()` comes to mind. This shouldn't be necessary with your test data (contains no single quotes after serialization), but it can be with other data.

Comment: It works now I used qoutes, thank you for your suggestions I will take look on how to unserilzed from base64_encode again thank you so much :)